# Return JSON object from nvarchar

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following table in Azure Sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
  [Id] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  [JsonData] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
```

With sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] VALUES ('abc', '{ "key1": 1, "key2" : "val1" }')
```

Now I would like to return array of properly formatted json object. I tried following:

```
SELECT id, jsonData  [md].[MyTable] 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

But this returns the json field as string:

```
{"deviceid":"abc", "jsonData" : "{ \"key1\": 1, \"key2\" : \"val1\" }" }
```

Aa you can see the jsonData is not an object, it's a string with escape \", whereas I need:

```
{"deviceid":"abc", "jsonData" : { "key1": 1, "key2" : "val1" } }
```

Comment: `FOR JSON AUTO` converts the *results* into JSON, it doesn't assume they contain JSON data. It sees a `jsonData` field with a string that need escaping.

Comment: yes, I've noticed. But I need a query that would return json as per question

Comment: Retrieved string is JSON String you can convert it in object, in any language or if you want in sql then replace(json,'\',''')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FOR JSON` with `JSON_QUERY()`, as is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-json_query-with-for-json) (*JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value*):

```
SELECT id, JSON_QUERY(jsonData) AS jsonData
FROM [MyTable] 
FOR JSON AUTO
```